# Why do dollar signs trigger MathJax

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeX Delimiters should be changed](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/tex-delimiters-should-be-changed)

I was looking at an old question of mine and discovered that the MathJax screws with a few of my comments: for instance, [the comment on this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/book-recommendations-for-digital-circuit-design/7799#7799)

The cause of this is that MathJax is triggered by dollar signs.

For instance: "I spent (dollarsign)60 here, but I should've only spent (dollarsign)40" in the below comment, will turn to MathJax

Why?

(Apparently, MathJax does the same thing on questions: I spent $60 here, but I should've only spent $40 )

Comment: I spent $60 here, but I should've only spent $40

Comment: We've already filed a bug report.  The StackExchange team chose `$...$` as the delimiters, against the [MathJax recommendations](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/start.html#tex-and-latex-input).  The default delimiters are `$$...$$`, `\[...\]`, and `\(...\)`.  Do you use those pairs of characters on the same line enough that your posts will be broken?

Comment: $\mbox{Because that's how it was configured.}$