# Issue/bug with inline mathjax equations

Tags: bug, status-completed, latex, mathjax

\$ V^{+}_{DUT}=0 \$

\$ V^{-}_{DUT}=Vout_{Servo}*\frac{50}{50k+50} \$

I think there is an issue with the mathjax escape detection. As you can see, (at least for me), the first line renders correctly, while the second line above does not get correctly detected as latex.

Using the *exact same* equations, with `$$` instead of `\$` for escape characters, you get:

$$ V^{+}_{DUT}=0 $$

$$ V^{-}_{DUT}=Vout_{Servo}*\frac{50}{50k+50} $$

It does this on Firefox and Opera, <strike>though I have not tested multiple computers</strike>.
Ok, I have now, and I see this issue everywhere.

---

Based on the question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/25117/1374), and my attempts to get it's TeX markup working.

Comment: First line renders correctly where the second does not, in my case too.

Comment: This mathjax stuff is slow, makes the window content pop around until it's done re-rendering stuff, confuses the browswer scrolling, and sometimes looks worse than ASCII art.  I just avoid it.

Comment: Wait, double dollar signs work here?  Why don't we just use that everywhere?  Isn't that the recommended delimiter? http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/501/142

Comment: @endolith - Double-dollar-signs force the resultant equation to be both centered, and on a new line. You cannot do in-line equations with them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You could always just block javascript, only downside is you are unable to add comments with it blocked. Something like noscript or notscript would let you toggle it off and on as desired. It takes less than a second for it to load for me though.

Answer (score 2):

The second line contains two underscores, which causes Markdown and \$\LaTeX\$ to trip over each other. This is usually prevented (by not running Markdown over equations), but this prevention didn't take the [peculiarities on electronics.se](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/tex-delimiters-should-be-changed/613#613) into account.

This is fixed in the next build of the site.