# Inline LaTeX doesn't seem to work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, latex, mathjax

Has anyone been able to make the inline LaTeX equation delimiter work??  I pulled the following example right from the advanced editing help example, and the LaTeX just won't happen!

The *Gamma function* satisfying $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall
n\in\mathbb N$ is via through the Euler integral

I see a couple of Completed Tags for this, like [enter link description here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/issue-bug-with-inline-mathjax-equations), but it's still a problem, at least in chrome 22.0.1229.94

Answer (score 17):

The inline delimiter is `\$` on this site since just the `$` delimiter creates havoc with anything that has prices in it. Last time I checked, we're the only site that does things this way, so they aren't going to change the help text for us.

`\$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N\$`

\$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N\$

Comment: `\$` is ok (though my first reaction was wtf?), but please add `\(` and `\)` http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5984/please-add-to-delimiters-for-inline-mathjax

Answer (score 4):

I keep this meta post favorited so I can refer back to how the EE.SE site likes it's MathJax:

[Test the new LaTeX markdown in this Sandbox question!](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question)

Comment: I thought mathjax also suggested something like \$ and SE just chose $ because they did not envision a site with prices, it made our site look like hell.

Comment: @Kortuk I don't know the history of SE's implementation of MathJax. But according to the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/options/tex2jax.html): "the single dollar signs are not enabled by default because they are used too frequently in normal text, so if you want to use them for math delimiters, you must specify them explicitly". So you're right. There defiantly was a conscious decision to implement the single dollar sign delimiter.

Comment: Maybe somebody thought the Euro would take over.