# Please add \( \) to delimiters for inline MathJax

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

(see also [Inline LaTeX doesn't seem to work](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/inline-latex-doesnt-seem-to-work))

I see that this site uses the nonstandard `\$` delimiters to MathJax rather than `\(` and `\)` which are used in most other sites. Since MathJax allows multiple delimiters, and asymmetrical delimiters are more robust, could you add these?

syntax as per http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html :

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ['\\$','\\$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ]
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a common thing for all stackexchange sites, you might want to ask on meta.se for that

Comment: @PlasmaHH, actually other SE sites just use `$` as delimiters for inliine MathJax. It was changed for EE because we are likely to  talk about how much things cost.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think *anyone* (well, except maybe the math sites where MathJax is the norm for many posts) should just use a plain `$` for this same reason. Expressing costs is such a common use case.

Comment: @ThePhoton: That may be, but that isn't a reason not to support `\(` ... `\)` as well.

Comment: The reason they don't use `\(` and `\)` is that it conflicts with the Markdown usage.  Parentheses have special meaning in Markdown in some situations (like for URLs following image references or link text), and a backslash is used in Markdown for escaping that special meaning.  You would have to use `\\(` and `\\)` in your posts to allow the backslash through to MathJax, and I suspect that was deemed too complicated and error prone.

Comment: ? Which variant of Markdown? I've been using Python's Markdown library + MathJax for several years using `\(` and `\)` with no problems whatsoever.