# Why does our inline syntax for Mathjax different from say, the Math SE?

Tags: bug, mathjax

I noticed that in our Stackexchange, the inline for Mathjax is different from the Math SE or Physics SE.

For the Math and Physics SE, the way the inline for their equations for Mathjax equations is: `$ equation $`

However, on our website, the way we inline our equations is: `\$ equation \$`.

Why is that? Is it a different version of Mathjax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relevant Post: [TeX Delimiters should be changed](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/tex-delimiters-should-be-changed?rq=1)

Basically, the initial SE implementation of MathJax decided to use the `$ ... $` syntax despite the following notice in the documentation:

> Note in particular that the $...$ in-line delimiters are not used by default. That is because dollar signs appear too often in non-mathematical settings, which could cause some text to be treated as mathematics unexpectedly.

I'm guessing it was originally for a "pure" site that never has to worry about the cost of components, so they thought it should never be a problem.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose there are could be some engineering questions that have to do with engineering economics.