# Is it possible to add inline-mathjax support like the other StackExchange sites document?

Tags: feature-request

I am accustomed to inline-math with MathJax support on many Stack Exchange sites.  For electrical engineering, equations are a really big part of circuit modeling.  $I_{DS}$ for instance is used to describe the Drain-Source current in a n-channel MOSFET transistors on other Stack Exchange sites, and new users can get confused.  Other sites have this inline use of math work perfectly, which is widely documented on these other sites.  I appreciate it if this could be an added feature as the raw MathJax code inline looks very ugly currently. \$I_{DS}\$ seems to work thankfully.

I saw [this link Why does our inline syntax for Mathjax different from say, the Math SE](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/why-does-our-inline-syntax-for-mathjax-different-from-say-the-math-se) only after writing this question, and now I am handling it like referenced.  But I think it would be best if there is not this inconsistency among the various Stack Exchange sites to make it more direct for newer users to write equations, who are more familiar with the extensive equation formatting documentation for the other sites.  Maybe an inline-math link could be added to make it easier for authors to be more aware of this difference.

Thank you for your help and consideration.

P.S.  I am also testing the not-inline math:

$$V_{be}=V_{b}-V_{e}$$

It seems to work the usual way using $$ to start and finish the equation.

Be careful though about using twice $$ on a single line.

Here is an example:  $$V_1+V_2=V_3$$  It automatically starts a stand-alone equation on a new line.

When editing text there is also a link to [Advanced Help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which includes the unique formatting:

[image: Math Formatting Picture from the Advanced Help]

That information is everything needed to insert an inline math equation and also to insert a stand-alone equation.  The extra link "MathJax Help" should not then be needed.

Comment: I second your request. But unfortunately, it doesn't matter how well-warranted, reasonable and upvoted a request is: Nothing will ever be adjusted at StackExchange. So I'm afraid, we just have to cope. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already do have inline MathJax support, using the `\$` delimiter that you used in your \$I_{DS}\$ example in the question.

> I think it would be best if there is not this inconsistency among the various Stack Exchange sites

It was deliberately configured on this site to use the `\$` not `$` delimiter, as cost (i.e. money and therefore currency) gets mentioned here, and we don't want that to trigger the MathJax parser.

So as far as I can tell about what you are asking, the difference in the inline MathJax delimiter between SE sites is a deliberate decision, not a bug, and not something that we want to change (unless you know a way to stop people using `$` in their posts, when talking about the cost of things).

Comment: Thank you for your insight as to why "$" recquires a slash in front of it, because cost articles need to reference the currency.  Cost is also very important in electrical engineering.  It seems then that your answer thus explains my question:  "Is it possible ...";  Also the advanced help does reference the unique formatting.  It has a link to MathJax though (see the picture) that seems to me a little confusing still to me as most of the formatting is for a document there.  I think your answer is pretty good so I am giving it the "check";  thank you!

Comment: Might be nice if MathJax could be added as an icon on the Answer and Question edit windows, to avoid bad user experiences

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Hi, (a) If you want to make a new feature request for that, please write a separate Meta post detailing the reasons & aims. (b) To be honest, considering the trend of [personnel changes in SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393806) and the fact that we have something which works currently, I think you would need to make a *compelling* case for that change to have any chance to be accepted by SE. (c) However if you put together the case then we can discuss it and then request its evaluation by SE - but I'm not hopeful of it getting resourced (because of (b) above). Thanks.

Comment: 1) Equations are a far more important part on this site than dollar symbols. 2) Dollars could be written also eg. as "USD", "dollars", `&$;` or `\$`.

Comment: "unless you know a way to stop people using $ in their posts, when talking about the cost of things" They should use £ or €, of course.

Comment: @GrahamNye - Nice try :) I think you'll have an uphill struggle to implement that change in the USA, but I admire your bravery in suggesting it :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Sam says about the reason, also consider that *changing* it, at this point, would require mass editing thousands if not millions of questions and answers, which, besides being a lot of work, would be a heavy load on the database.

And it would require that all of our best answerers would need to break the habit of typing `\$` built up over years of answering questions.

Comment: The edit could easily be handled by a bot doing auto-replace. Top answerers would get used to the simpler style very easily  Plus new answerers would not need to learn it the awkward EESE way.