# Help page about embedding LaTeX is wrong, needs fixin'

Tags: support, mathjax

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex is plain wrong, `$x$` doesn't work on EE.SE, `\$x\$` does (which, honestly, is super annoying, because we're dealing with far more math than finances).

Could someone fix that page?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, this is an issue on at least one other site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348676/295232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for raising the issue, I see it's been escalated and I hope the help will be fixed.

As per why we use the escaped dollar sign, [here's the explanation.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/tex-delimiters-should-be-changed)

Comment: Thank you for picking this up! But also: I know we can't change the past, and I don't see a good solution for existing `\$` questions to coexist with potentialy new `$`-only answers if we should ever decide to change that, but the reasoning for the escaped dollar sign is simply not very good, imho (most users here are probably *no* US-based anymore, and we really do less pricing and more math by now).

Comment: @MarcusMüller the issue is with breaking all previous questions & answers, unless we find a way to automatically convert all tags

Comment: exactly what I meant with "can't change the past". (it probably wouldn't be hard to find all usages of dollar signs outside of code-formatted regions, but 9 years later, there's already so much broken legacy code, that doing that would break things in new ways, so, meh, agreeing with you: it's too late to change things now. The decision from back then was just, in my humble hindsight, a bit short-sighted and US-centric. Also, Jeff displayed a pretty strong misunderstanding of the community domain of expertise in his downvoted answer there.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Clearly we should change the MathJax delimiter to "€". That way the only international change we have to do is put instructions for ALT-codes in the LaTeX user guide. (sarcasm off) I think EE.SE still needs to be able to discuss prices, as that's still a major part of engineering (case study: Juicero). I still strongly agree with everything in that post, even as we've seen the site mature to talk less about pricing. It's not so much that we expect to be discussing price continuously, but that the site provides a *bad* experience when you do.