Is there a way to display multiple lines of equations in display mode on this site?
Is there a way to display multiple lines of equations in display mode on this site?
On other SE sites, you can do the following:
\$$ % Initial slash not needed on other sites
I = C \frac{dV}{dt} \\
R = V/I
$$

and the equations will be on separate lines.  On this site, however, that doesn't seem to work. Example: How to analyze a current sink for an ideal power amplifier

Without the back-slash it does work on this site. Saying that something doesn't seem to work is no help at all to understanding what issue you face. Linking to an example that shows formulas on different lines and the same lines confuses the issue for me.

@Andyaka Someone edited the example to fix it, after I posted this question.  On other SE sites, you enter LaTeX with a $.  On electronics.SE, you need to do a \\$.  I saw a post on meta explaining why. Apparently, the requirement for the slash is only for a single $ and not a double $$.  Documenting that somewhere would help people new to this site.

It seems that both \$$ and $$ work, but the first disables newlines and the second doesn't.

Look at the edit history = nobody edited anything important to your formatting misunderstanding.

I removed the status review tag off this since it seems like this was a formatting issue and not an actual bug.

@SRobertJames  see https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/tex-delimiters-should-be-changed -- our inline delimiter is $, so $$ seems to be doing something odd that's causing problems.

@ScottSeidman There seems to be a formatting issue making your comment not display properly.

You have this latex/mathjax (or whatever it is) in your linked question: -
\$$ I_{src} = I_0 e^{j \omega t} \\ V_{L} = V_1 - L \frac{dI_{src}}{dt} \\ = V_1 -jI_{src} \omega L$$
and that produces what you appear to not want: -
$$
I_{src} = I_0 e^{j \omega t} \
V_{L} = V_1 - L \frac{dI_{src}}{dt} \
= V_1 -jI_{src} \omega L$$
But, if you removed the slash in the beginning you get this: -
$$
I_{src} = I_0 e^{j \omega t} \\
V_{L} = V_1 - L \frac{dI_{src}}{dt} \\
= V_1 -jI_{src} \omega L$$
So, what's the issue here?

FWIW, the MathJax delimiters we use on this stack are not the "standard" MathJax delimiters, or the delimiters used on other stacks.
